# 18.04 Ubuntu Texmaker “Could not Start the Command” Error

Tags: ubuntu

I've posted this yesterday in the Ubuntu StackExchange but I thought why not here too.

I do get the Error

```
"Could not start the command"
```

every time I want to compile a document and I can't explain why. (It hast the addition - "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex" because this process is supposed to run but Texmaker can't find it?) I have deleted and reinstalled both texlive and texmaker (currently I have the texlive-latex-extra package installed).

I have also created a tex Document with an editor and compiling it to pdf using the terminal and it worked fine, which basically means that I've installed the texlive package the right way?

So I'm really not understanding whats wrong with my installation.

If anything else is needed to solve this Problem I'm happy to give more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you installed TeXLive? With the package manager or from tug.org/texlive/ ??

Comment: I have installed it via the package manager in the terminal. Is tug.org/texlive/ the better way to go?
Right now I'm trying to install the texlive-full package.

Comment: How exactly did you add TeXLive to the PATH and hos do you start TeXMaker? This situation usually comes from users adding the PATH change to `.bashrc` and starting TeXMaker from a menu or similar. Add the PATH change to `.profile` log out and in again and try once more. (we see this problem a lot)

Comment: If you installed it with the package manager then `pdflatex` should be found. What is the output of `which pdflatex` in a terminal??

Comment: Usually I start Texmaker by clicking on the shortcut after searching for it. This time after a new installation I started it in the terminal. Here is a screenshot of my "configure texmaker" window https://imgur.com/a/EQBVFkG . All my settings are not changed as of yet. 
Sadly I don't quit understand what you mean with the adding the PATH change to .profile as I'm not so experienced with this kind of topics. Can you go into a little bit more detail?

Comment: The Output of which pdflatex is 
'/usr/bin/pdflatex' @Herbert

Comment: That output looks fine. Open a terminal, go into the directory of any tex file and run `pdflatex <myfile>` Does it run?  If yes, then you should delete texmaker and install TeXstudio, it is the successor to texmaker

Comment: @herbert I'm not sure you can see TeXStudio as a successor to TeXMaker, they just went seperate ways.

Comment: That sounds strange, TeXMaker should not have any issues with a TeXLive from Ubuntu. Have you been messing with any settings in your Linux? Also does `texmaker` work if you start it from the command line instead of from a menu?

Comment: @Herbert I can create PDFs using the pdflatex command in the terminal it works fine. I just double checked and created this example https://imgur.com/a/C5eCm8t ... I can try using TeXstudio, however I'm still interested in whats wrong with Texmaker.

Comment: @daleif I did not mess with my Linux Settings (at least not that I am aware of...) Strange thing is I've had Texmaker working previously on this system but did not use it for a year or so. Last time I used it I was still running 16.04 and since then I have upgraded to 18.04. Could this somehow be a problem?

Comment: Okay... TexStudio works fine (I cant't explain why tho...). However I'd still prefer using texmaker as I am quite familiar with it. Do you think there is any way of getting it working again?

Comment: Little Update: TeXStudio works fine. If I create a .tex File with TexStudio and compile it open that File with Texmaker I can use Texmaker too. However creating new Files with Texmaker still isn't working. I really can't wrap my head around whats wrong here...

Comment: Tra to save the new file first before you run texmaker. Does it help?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling texmaker?

Comment: @Herbert You mean saving the file in texmaker? I tried this already, but can do again.

Comment: @daleif yes, I think I have tried reinstalling texmaker three times so far :/

Comment: @sncyth Are you still facing this issue? Try resetting the settings from the options and/or delete the settings.ini file.